# Is there anyway to instead of doing explicit instantiation of a template code for DLL, deliver the code itself somehow implementation-hidden?

Tags: c++, dll, implementation, instantiation

If a template code is about to be used for DLL the explicit instantiation should be applied to produce the binary but I want to know Is there anyway not to do explicit instantiation but to deliver the source-code somehow implementation-hidden to the end-user so that his/her compiler can does the instantiation itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `export` keyword was invented for. Sadly, almost no compiler ever implemented it, and AFAIK, it will be deprecated in C++1x.